# System crash after using sprintf

Tags: arduino-uno

My Arduino crashes after using sprintf, To reduce system ram am trying to move away from strings to char and now this happened. Loop not working properly and it's not going to webrequest, spent 2 days to find a solution nothing worked yet. My project is to send temp and humidly to my server i was using strings and after one day of use system very slow to send data to server then i realized stings are the culprit then i changed to char

```
char ventionoroff[6];

char Foggeronoroff[6] ;

char Exhuastonoroff[6] = "OFF";

char current[4];

char today[10];

bool running = false;
bool isFoggerRunning = false;
bool isExhaustFanRunning = false;





Time t;


void loop() {


  
 t = rtc.getTime();

  hum = dht.readHumidity();
  temp = dht.readTemperature();
  delay(1000);
  
  if (isnan(hum) || isnan(temp)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }
  val = digitalRead(powerStatus);


      byte MIN = t.hour;
      byte SEC = t.min;
     
  char timeStamp[20];
 snprintf(today, "%02d:%02d",  MIN, SEC);

   Serial.println(today);


if (millis() - lastConnectionTime > postingInterval) {
   Serial.println("reaching here2");
    httpRequest();
  }

  if (val)
  snprintf( current , "YES");
   
  else
 snprintf( current , "NO");
   
 
  if (running == false) {
    snprintf( Foggeronoroff , "WAIT");
   
  } else {
   snprintf( Foggeronoroff , "READY");
   
  }
  
    ventilationfan();
  






void httpRequest() {
Serial.println("shit reached here");
  client.stop();
  char data[10];
  const char phpScript[21]  = "";
  const char server[20]  =  ""; // also change the Host line in httpRequest()

   char strt[6];
   char str[6];
  sprintf(strt, "te=%d", temp);
  strcpy(data, strt);
  strcat (data,"&ti=");
  strcat (data,today);
   strcat (data,"&mot=");
   strcat (data,ventionoroff);
   strcat (data,",");
   strcat (data,Foggeronoroff);
    strcat (data,",");
    strcat (data,current);
     strcat (data,"&mo=");
     strcat (data,Exhuastonoroff);
      sprintf(str, "&hum=%d",hum);
      strcat (data,str);
       
 Serial.println(data);
   int len = strlen(data);
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    client.print("POST ");
    client.print(phpScript);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host:");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(len);
    client.println();
    client.print(data);
    restartnet = 0;
     data[0] = 0;
     Serial.print("data after sucessfull connection");
     Serial.println(data);
     Serial.print("freeMemory after connection");
     Serial.println(freeMemory());
    lastConnectionTime = millis();
   
  } else {
    
     Serial.println(F("Failed"));
     data[0] = 0;
   
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean this line? `sprintf(strt, "te=%d", temp);` - Are you sure, that `temp` will only have 2 digits? Which type is `temp`? You didn't include the declaration of it in your question. And why are you doing all the `strcat()` calls? Why not just using snprintf with a bigger format string, including all the data together?

Comment: it doesn't look like `data` is large enough

Comment: And when using `snprintf()`, shouldn't you also provide the maximum number of characters to write, as this function is meant for that?

Comment: @chrisl ttemp is temperature value, i tried to do that but get errors new to sprintf so no idea how to implement to make string

Comment: @Juraj new to sprintf , dont know how to deal with it , what i need to do then?

Comment: the array size should reflect the count of characters you concatenate into it. does it make sense?

Comment: @Juraj Yeah, actually i still don't know why my system  crash.

Comment: @Juraj can you show me an example how to declare global char that change status like , on ,off

Comment: you rewrite a memory of other variable if you write out of the allocated space. it looks like you write around 30 characters more then your arrays size `data[10]`

Comment: @Juraj i got that, i changed the size to 30. does the system reuse [30] the memory after use?

Comment: count the characters and create a large enough array. I said 30 more so I guess 40. it is a local variable allocated on 'stack'.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation

Comment: @Juraj After changing to [30] system works looks fine now, if you dont mind can you show me an example to put big strings in sprintf ? because my purpose is to send data to server with webservice  i used strcat insted of sprintf the problem with the strcat ( is i need to empty every time

Comment: `sprintf_P(buff, PSTR("%-15s|%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d|% 5d|% 5d|% 3u|"), eventLongLabels[ix], year(t), month(t), day(t), hour(t), minute(t), second(t),
 events[ix].value1, events[ix].value2, events[ix].count);` https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few points that could be improved in this code. The
main ones have already been shown in the comments:

1. the `data` buffer was not large enough to hold the whole string,
   which leads to a buffer overflow, memory corruption and, ultimately,
   the crash you are experiencing.
2. The second parameter to `snprintf()` should be the size of the
   provided buffer.

Here I will add a few points that, although not really defects of this
program, could help improved it and save memory.

Here:

```cpp
char current[4];
// ...
if (val)
    snprintf(current, "YES");
else
    snprintf(current, "NO");
```

you are not using the `current` buffer to build a string, but only to
store one of two pre-existing strings (the literals `"YES"` and `"NO"`)
that are already stored in memory. Rather than making a copy, you could
instead reuse those pre-existing strings, and have `current` be a
pointer to the relevant one:

```cpp
const char *current;
// ...
if (val)
    current = "YES";
else
    current = "NO";
```

This only saves two bytes (size of the buffer minus size of the
pointer), but this pattern happens multiple times in the program, and
the savings add up.

Now, another small optimization. Here:

```cpp
char strt[6];
sprintf(strt, "te=%d", temp);
strcpy(data, strt);
```

you do not need the extra `strt` buffer, as you can write directly into
the `data` buffer. Better yet, you can write *everything* into the
buffer in a single call to `snprintf()`:

```cpp
snprintf(data, sizeof data,
        "te=%d&ti=%02d:%02d&mot=%s,%s,%s&mo=%s&hum=%d",
        temp, t.hour, t.min, ventionoroff, Foggeronoroff, current,
        Exhuastonoroff, hum);
```

If you don't like this approach, and would prefer writing the data in
separate calls to `snprintf()`, you can do so without using auxiliary
buffers. You have to remember (with a pointer) where within the buffer
you finished your previous write, and pass this address to the next
`snprintf()` call. Note that you also have to keep track of the room
that is still available, which is easy to do with a second pointer that
points to the end of the buffer:

```cpp
char *p = data;                  // current writing position
char *end = data + sizeof data;  // end of the buffer
p += snprintf(p, end - p, "te=%d", temp);
p += snprintf(p, end - p, "&ti=%s", today);
// ...
```

Comment: snprintf(data, sizeof data, "te=%d&ti=%d&mot=%s,%s,%s&mo=%s&hu=%d",
        temp, today, ventionoroff, Foggeronoroff, current,
        Exhuastonoroff, hum);  'today' actualy rtc time , but i get 825 in that char not time , i serial printed the today and i got the time but sending 825 to server dont know where it come

Comment: @user2037091: `today` was an array of `char` in the original code. Anyway, I amended the answer in order to print `t.hour` and `t.min` instead. This saves an extra auxiliary buffer.